# Pattern for correctly displaying planets

Tags: 3d

I have 3D scene, with bay I can walk in first person, and planet seen from the window, taking all view. How should I draw planet, so it will display correctly?

My bay dimensions are 10x10x7. And I run into three options, all with drawbacks:

1. Just hang radius=8 planet near the window. Well, it is perceived like hung out cheese, when I look at the window and press forward or backpedal, I see it scaling. Worst
2. Make two scenes and two cameras, one for bay, second for planet. Looks best, but only if I do not turn. If I turn, it is clearly visible that planet is just a skybox background
3. Natural way. Place planet in a thousands units away, with thousands units radius. Just can't make my so called "engine" to get this working. Clipping planes and depth buffer problems are just top of the iceberg. Should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many ways, your problem has the same requirements as [Skyboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_%28video_games%29). So, you could read up a bit on how they work and apply a solution based on that.
For example:

1. You always want to render the planet first, so that it ends up behind everything else. This enables you to place it nearby (and so avoid z-clipping).
2. You want it to always appear at the same distance from the player.
   To achieve this you can apply the technique found here: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial25/tutorial25.html
   They have a custom vertex shader that replaces the z-value, so it doesn't scale.
   I'm sure you can find other ways if you don't want to use a shader.

Edit:
I think the most naive method would be to offset the position of the planet by the players position each frame. Combined with 1. the planet would appear to be stationary and yet far away.